# React Native Androids has problem value.at is not a function. (in 'value.at(-1)'), 'value.at' is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, runtime-error

i'm trying to use new function in js [at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) but i have  `value.at is not a function. (in 'value.at(-1)'), 'value.at' is undefined` error on Android. I am using expo to run react native also program normally works when i running it on Iphone or web browser

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by using

```
value[value.length-1]
```

Instead of .at(). It does seem to be a bug in Expo.

Comment: The same happens even without Expo when disptaching with redux but only on Android...

Answer (score -1):

This case, 'value' is not array.

Check type of 'value'. ex) `console.log(typeof value)`

Comment: This is made in comments, not in answers

Comment: ok... next time i will... :/ thx